# How to add 2 UIpickerViews into one UIview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview

I am a little bit confused. I have one main `UIView` and I've pasted 2 `UIViews` in the main one.
In each "child"-`UIView` I have a `UIPickerView`. My problem is that I have the following functions for the 1-st  `UIPickerView`, but don't know how to do such for second one. Can anybody help me with that?

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIViewController *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIViewController *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if(component==option)
        return[options count];
    return 0;

}


-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIViewController *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component==option)
         return[options objectAtIndex:row];
    return 0;
}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _optionLabel.text=[options objectAtIndex:[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}
```

So, are there any ways to do copies of these functions to my 2nd pickerView?

Comment: Use the `pickerView` parameter of each method to determine which picker view is being processed. Return the proper data for each.

Comment: You don't need 2 UIPickerView, rather you need 2 datasource, toggle between datasource as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to set picker view tag Like this

```
#Updated

myPickerView.tag = 1;  //It's for first PickerView
directionTranslationPickerView.tag = 2;  //It's for second PickerView
```

Please Implement this two line where you create your pickerview .

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    if (pickerView.tag==1) {
        return 1; //It's for first PickerView
    }else{
        return 1; // It's for second pickerview
    }

}


- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (pickerView.tag==1) {
        if(component==option)
            return[options count]; //It's for first PickerView
        return 0;

    }else{

        // It's for second pickerview
        return 0;

    }

}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.view.tag==1) {
        if(component==option)
            return[options objectAtIndex:row]; //It's for first PickerView
        return 0;
    }else{
        // It's for second pickerview
    }

}


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.view.tag==1) {
        _optionLabel.text=[options objectAtIndex:[myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]; //It's for first PickerView

    }else{
        // It's for second pickerview
    }
}
```

Try this may be helpfull for you. 
Note : You need to set tag must for your UIPickerView

Comment: Thanks, but how and where I have to write pickerViewObg.tag=1 and pickerViewObj.tag= 2 if my picker views are "myPickerView" and directionTranslationPickerView. I mean how to connect them?

Comment: I have updated my answer. You need to set tag where you create your pickerviews. Try this.. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, that doesn't work. It says: Unknown type name "myPickerView"; did you mean 'UIPickerView'? " So, any ideas?)

Comment: Sure.  IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPickerView; IBOutlet UIPickerView *directionTranslationPickerView; I've created those tags in ViewDidLoad, and there are no any errors, but now I cannot run my simulator cuz "Thread1: signal..." appears

Comment: Please set both pickerview's tag in ViewDidLoad.

Comment: I have done everything you told me, but now I try to run my app, on the line where 'if(pickerView.view.tag==1){' is written the "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.3" message appears. Do you know what that means?

Comment: Hello... Sorry for that . You datasource function are not currect .. I am updating my answer again. Try this after update..

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above as an option, but wouldn't rule out putting each picker in its own UIView subclass and making those subviews of the one view.  The advantage to this is that it allows you to keep the code separate which for me, at least, is easier to maintain.  The downside is that you can end up with a lot of delegates back-and-forth.